# Issues with properly returning data in C# API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

Apologies for the vague title, i am not sure how to exactly explain it. What i want to do is return a list of 2 items (listName & timeCreated) from a SQLServer DB depending on if the accompanying userid sent through the HttpGet request matches. Current code (pasted below) returns only an empty object but with the correct amount of indexes and looks something like this: [{},{}], when i want it to return something like: [{"item1": "listname","item2": "2023-04-21T14:30:52.76"}].

Using VS2022 to build the ASP.NET Core Web Api and ran debugging, the "lists" var does contain the desired data so i am baffled as to why it doesn't actually return it. Again, sorry for the trouble, any help is appreciated.

```
private readonly UserInfoHandlingService _userInfoHandling;
        private readonly ListDataHandlingService _listDataHandlingService;

        public RequestHandlingController(UserInfoHandlingService userInfoHandling, ListDataHandlingService listDataHandlingService)
        {
            _userInfoHandling = userInfoHandling;
            _listDataHandlingService = listDataHandlingService;
        }
```

```
[HttpGet("getAllLists")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoadAllLists([FromBody] Requests content)
        {
            string targetUserId = content.userId;
            var lists = await _listDataHandlingService.LoadAllLists(targetUserId);
            return Ok(lists);
        }
```

```
public async Task<List<(string listName, DateTime timeCreated)>> LoadAllLists(string targetUserId)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT listName, timeCreated FROM [dbo].[jsonList] WHERE userid = @userid", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", targetUserId);

                    using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        var responseList = new List<(string listName, DateTime timeCreated)>();

                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            responseList.Add((reader.GetString(0), reader.GetDateTime(1)));
                        }
                        return responseList;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What confuses me even more is that i've used the same piece of code/logic in a previous project and it worked as desired and still does yet this is un-cooperative.

Comment: Which framework is your previous project used? ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core WebAPI? While I doubt that it is not possible to return the response with tuple because it is not serializable (correct me if I am wrong). You should return the response with model class/anonymous object that can be serialized rather than tuple.

Comment: Previous project used ASP.NET Core WebAPI also. I will using what you suggested, will comment again with the results soon.

Comment: Gave it a shot, i must've missunderstood something since i am still at a very novice level, but i appreciate the help! Tried Xinran's solution below and it worked so if you're facing a similar issue, highly suggested checking it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, You can create a class as response type.

For example, My table looks like this:

[image]

Then I create a class as response type:

```
public class ReturnType
    {
        public int DataListId { get; set; }
        public string DataListValue { get; set; }
    }
```

I modify LoadAllLists method like

```
public async Task<List<ReturnType>> LoadAllLists(int targetUserId)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT DataListId, DataListValue FROM [dbo].[dataListItems] WHERE DataListId = @userid", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", targetUserId);

                    using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        List<ReturnType> responseList = new List<ReturnType>();

                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            responseList.Add(new ReturnType()
                            {
                                DataListId = reader.GetInt32(0),
                                DataListValue = reader.GetString(1)
                            });
                           
                        }
                        return responseList;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Result

[image]

Hope it is what you want.